Select specific fields in JSON using openjson
I am trying to select specific fields from a JSON column in SQL Server and return the result as JSON itself preserving the JSON datatypes using openjson. The JSON fields are dynamic and hence I do not know the field types ahead of time to use an explicit schema.
For example, I want the ConfigId and the Data column in JSON format with appName, isEnabled, domains and maxUsers fields
Input



ConfigID
Name
Data




1
application1
{"appName" : "app-1", "createdBy" : "John", "isEnabled" : false, "domains" : ["domain1","domain2","domain3"], "maxUsers" : 100}


2
application2
{"appName" : "app-2", "createdBy" : "Peter", "isEnabled" : true, "domains" : ["domain1"], "site" : "abc.com" }



Expected Output



ConfigID
Data




application1
{"appName" : "app-1", "isEnabled" : false, "domains" : ["domain1","domain2","domain3"], "maxUsers" : 100}


application2
{"appName" : "app-2", "isEnabled" : true, "domains" : ["domain1"] }



For now, I am retrieving the field, type and value and creating a flat JSON using the application code that queries the db
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=4f2f3e57-930b-4fb9-b058-46a8a34b353c.
I am trying to figure out a way to do this in a single SQL query using openjson?

What is the SQL Server version?

If the information in the fiddle is important, please include it in the question. I opened the fiddle but then when I declined the cookies it took me away and I wasn't able to access the SQL you provided.

Additional reading is this Q&A.

@Zhorov - I am using SQL server 2016. Thanks. the solution that you posted in the other link should work. I wish there was a simpler way to achieve this in SQL server.

Try Select query:
SELECT 
    ConfigID,
    (SELECT appName, isEnabled, domains, maxUsers
     FROM OPENJSON(Data) 
     WITH (
        appName nvarchar(100) '$.appName',
        isEnabled bit '$.isEnabled',
        domains nvarchar(max) '$.domains' AS JSON,
        maxUsers int '$.maxUsers'
     )
     FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS Data
FROM YourTableName


Thanks. Unfortunately, this solution will not work for me as I do not know all the fields and their types ahead of time. The field names that I posted is just an example from one of the json's.
